# Connecting Docker Windows WSL Ubuntu to VMware Ubuntu

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to connect my Windows 10 Home system to be able to run full Linux OS Docker containers. I have installed Docker on both WSL Ubuntu 18.04 as well as a VMware Ubuntu 18.04.

I was trying to follow [this guide](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly).

However, I get stuck trying to configure the Daemon as per the instructions.

> Can’t use Docker for Windows?
>   This is only necessary if you are NOT running Docker for Windows!
>
> No problem, just configure your Docker daemon to use `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 and --tlsverify=false`. Then you can follow along with the rest of this guide exactly.
>
> If you go down this route, I highly recommend rolling your own VM with VMware Player instead of using the Docker Toolbox because VirtualBox has crazy edge case shared folder bugs that will ruin your life at some point. Don’t worry, VMware Player is free. Just Google how to set up Ubuntu 16 server on VMware Player.

When I try to change the Docker Daemon by making a `daemon.json` file I get errors. I've also tried editing the `.profile` files and the `.bashrc` as per [other guides](https://blog.jayway.com/2017/04/19/running-docker-on-bash-on-windows/) ([another guide](https://codingrandomly.com/2018/06/docker-command-line-wsl/)), with no luck.

I am unable to check the DOCKER_HOST variable on the VM Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Don't make things complicated. In your case, why WSL if you just want to connect to a remote daemon? Why not simply use the windows docker client?

1. Setup you favorite local VM with docker.
   Example: I have installed a CentOS distro running on local VMWare Workstation. All Hyper-V of course deinstalled/deactivated.
2. In this VM, enable tcp access for the daemon.
   If you have a systemd linux distro (like mine CentOS), execute this:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

   sudo echo '[Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375' >> /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf

   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl restart docker`
   ```
3. Test if the port is open with `docker info`. You should get an API access warning at the bottom result.
4. Download the Windows docker cli zip from here: https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/
   Move the docker.exe to any folder, for ex. your Documents folder.
   Then put this folder path into your Windows PATH variable.
5. Set the docker host: Open PowerShell, execute `setx DOCKER_HOST <VM-IP>:2375` and close it.
6. Open a new PowerShell and call `docker info`.
   You should see the docker and daemon infos.

Do what ever you like now... :-)